# Want to update value in database. But it says update() on null

Tags: database

I want to update a column value in my database table. I have a form, by submitting this form i am redirecting to another page named `verify.php` and trying to update column value. But is says Call to a member function update() on null .
here is my form code:

```
<form action="verify.php" method="POST">
<input type="text" value="'.esc_attr($result->wp_user_id).'" name="providerId">
<input type="text" name="verify">
<button> Verify</button>
</form>
```

and here in my `verify.php` code

```
<?php
global $wpdb;
//$postData = extract($_POST);
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
        //global $wpdb;
        $wpdb->update('service_finder_providers',
            array(
                'is_nidverified' => 'Yes'
            ),
            array( 'id' => 60 ),
                array( 
                    '%s'
                ), 
        array( '%s' ) 
);
}
```

It says Call to a member function update() on null

Comment: If you redirect to another page, the `$wpdb` global will no longer exist.

Comment: then what should i do to run this update query

Answer (score 0):

Your `verify.php` files lives outside WordPress framework, so $wpdb and everything else is not available.

Correct way is to use `admin_post_` hook. You can read about it [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_post_(action)).

This goes in functions.php

```
add_action( 'admin_post_add_foobar', 'prefix_admin_add_foobar' );

function prefix_admin_add_foobar() {
    //$wpdb->update()
}
```

And the form:

```
<form action="<?php echo esc_url(admin_url('admin-post.php')); ?>" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="action" value="add_foobar">
  <input type="hidden" name="data" value="foobarid">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Simpler but **not recommended** solution is to init WordPress inside your `verify.php` file, at the top add (replace ../../../ with correct path to the file):

```
require_once('../../../wp-load.php');
```

Comment: then should I run my update query in function.php ?

Comment: @Fokrule I'm not sure I understand your question. Please re-read the answer, it has all the details you need.

Comment: @Fokrule Update query will be inside the hook in the functions.php file yes, but you will be accessing it via call to `/wp-admin/admin-post.php` and correct hidden input with `add_foobar `.

Comment: @Fokrule I've added second, simpler, solution to your issue.

Comment: 1. The "simple" solution should never be mentioned in polite company. 2. getting the url for admin_post should be done using the relevant functions, and should never be hardcoded.

Comment: @MarkKaplun 1. Agreed. But unfortunately people still are using it, and it never hurts to give all possible options and let OP decide which way to go. 2. True, I updated the answer. WP docs should be updated too.